# Hudson does not execute tasks: FATAL: hudson.model.RunMap.access$900

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I set up hudson, and it works as a windows service.
When I start any job it immediately fails with next error:

FATAL: hudson.model.RunMap.access$900(Lhudson/model/RunMap;)Ljava/util/SortedMap;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.RunMap.access$900(Lhudson/model/RunMap;)Ljava/util/SortedMap;
    at hudson.model.RunMap$RunValue.update(RunMap.java:811)
    at hudson.model.RunMap$RunValueUpdater.onStarted(RunMap.java:1606)
    at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireStarted(RunListener.java:162)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1385)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)

Could someone advice how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

hudson 3.0.1 resolved the issue.